# /etc/shadow is empty, yet I am prompted for password

Tags: linux, login, embedded, buildroot, shadow

I have a board (Pine64) on which I run my custom-built linux distribution (using `buildroot`).

I configure `root` to have no password, and the resulting `/etc/shadow` file looks like this:

```
root::::::::
daemon:*:::::::
bin:*:::::::
sys:*:::::::
sync:*:::::::
mail:*:::::::
www-data:*:::::::
operator:*:::::::
nobody:*:::::::
avahi:*:::::::
dbus:*:::::::
mosquitto:*:::::::
sshd:*:::::::
```

My `/etc/passwd` looks like this:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/false
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/false
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/false
sync:x:4:100:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/spool/mail:/bin/false
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/false
operator:x:37:37:Operator:/var:/bin/false
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/home:/bin/false
avahi:x:1000:1000::/:/bin/false
dbus:x:1001:1001:DBus messagebus user:/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
mosquitto:x:1002:65534:Mosquitto user:/:/bin/false
sshd:x:1003:1002:SSH drop priv user:/var/empty:/bin/false
```

So as you can see there is no password set for `root`.

Yet when I try to login after boot, I am prompted for password, which I can't supply (because I didn't set one). Any value that I try yields an `incorrect password` message.

**IMPORTANT**: I'm booting my system with `nfsroot` so the root filesystem is mounted from an NFS share on my machine.

The owner of both `passwd` and `shadow` in my nfs folder is `root`, and only `root` is allowed to write to both.

So do you have any idea why I am still prompted for password even though I shouldn't be?

Answer (score 3):

By default, sshd doesn't allow empty passwords (cf. [PermitEmptyPasswords](https://manpath.be/c8/5/sshd_config#L738) and [AuthenticationMethods](https://manpath.be/c8/openssh-server/7.8p1-4.el8.x86_64/5/sshd_config#L121)).

There is also [UsePAM](https://manpath.be/c8/openssh-server/7.8p1-4.el8.x86_64/5/sshd_config#L996) (which is enabled, by default) which might result in your PAM configuration bailing out on empty passwords.

That said, do you really want to have a wide-open root account?

I mean, you could easily just set up public-key auth for the root user with a password-less private key. In that way you could log in without entering a password, but not everybody with network access could.